# Does HttpGet, HttpPost abort() method aborts the request even if it is taking more time to establish the connection

Tags: http, connection, httpclient, okhttp

I have a scenario where in certain cases request need to be terminated based on alternate configuration. From https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout I understood that we can set hard time out. However not sure how to test this.

Does the below code aborts the request with in given time even if there is a scenario of connection or socket or read timeout

```
HttpGet getMethod = new HttpGet(
  "http://localhost:8080/httpclient-simple/api/bars/1");

int hardTimeout = 5; // seconds
TimerTask task = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        if (getMethod != null) {
            getMethod.abort();
        }
    }
};
new Timer(true).schedule(task, hardTimeout * 1000);

HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(getMethod);
```

For instance if connection time out is set to 10 seconds and it is taking more than 10 seconds then does it terminate in 5 seconds. Similarly for other timeout scenarios.

If Apache httpclient library does not support this, is there an alternative?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Look [here](https://www.baeldung.com/httpclient-timeout) for setting connection and read timeouts with apache http client.

Comment: Please note that I have referred to the same link/page. Just want to understand or get confirmation that the hard timeout solution will abort the request in all possible time out scenarios.